# GitHub, SSH & OS X Keychain Access

Tags: github, ssh, terminal

Setting up GitHub, and Im using SSH to connect. Following along [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)to get all SSH set up. All is working well until i try to push an existing repository from the command line.

No problems with the following

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/first_app.git
```

But when I execut the following

```
git push -u origin master
```

things stop working.

My Keychain access dialog window pops up and wants the id_rsa password. Isn't this the passphrase I made up when i was following the steps on GitHub's how-to setup SSH? I think it is, but Keychain won't take the passphrase (I'm using this interchangeably with the word password).

I get: `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Can someone please help me connect the last piece of this puzzle so I can connect to GitHub via SSH? Thanks

Comment: If keychain access dialogs are popping up, they take your user account password, not the private key password. Did you add your public key to your Github account? Did you actually assign a password to your keypair or did you leave it blank?

Comment: @cjc343: Putting the user account password into keychain didn't work. The keychain dialogue box is specifically asking to "Enter your password for the SSH key "id_rsa". I did assign a passphrase to the key pair. When I was setting up SSH to work with GitHub I was prompted in Terminal to enter and reconfirm the passphrase.

Comment: My comment about keychain was about your keychain password prompt, which it sounds like wasn't actually for keychain. Not entering a password is a possibility. Did you add your public key to your Github account?